# Neovim - LSP attached to client but not working

Tags: neovim, lsp

I have this problem, that angularls is attached to my client, but the autocomplete / go to definition / format / hover is not working, for example if I tried to do vim.buf.hover using 'K' on '@Component' (An angular decorator), a message 'No information available' is printed.

I already installed angular language service as dev dependency in my project, and I also have logged my LSP, but I didn't see any errors. Can someone help me spot the mistake?

Plugins installed:

```
packer.nvim
mason.nvim
nvim-lspconfig
neodev.nvim
rust-tools.nvim
nvim-jdtls
nvim-dap
nvim-dap-ui
cmp-*
nvim-cmp
LuaSnip
cmp_luasnip
nvim-tree
nvim-lsp-file-operations
feline.nvim
telescope.nvim
nvim-treesitter
```

```
-- snipped
-- Angular
local uv = vim.loop
local function get_node_modules(root_dir)
    -- return util.find_node_modules_ancestor(root_dir) .. '/node_modules' or ''
    -- util.find_node_modules_ancestor()
    local root_node = root_dir .. "/node_modules"
    local stats = uv.fs_stat(root_node)
    if stats == nil then
        return ''
    else
        return root_node
    end
end

local default_node_modules = get_node_modules(vim.fn.getcwd())

local ngls_cmd = {
    "node",
    "/home/me/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/angular-language-server/node_modules/@angular/language-server/",
    "--stdio",
    "--tsProbeLocations",
    default_node_modules,
    "--ngProbeLocations",
    default_node_modules,
    "--includeCompletionsWithSnippetText",
    "--includeAutomaticOptionalChainCompletions",
    "--logToConsole",
    "--logFile",
    "/home/me/angularls.log",
}

lspconfig.angularls.setup {
    cmd = ngls_cmd,
    on_attach = on_attach,
    capabilities = capabilities,
    on_new_config = function(new_config, _)
        new_config.cmd = ngls_cmd
    end,
}
```

checkhealth:

```
==============================================================================
vim.lsp: require("vim.lsp.health").check()

- LSP log level : WARN
- Log path: /home/me/.local/state/nvim/lsp.log
- Log size: 1 KB

vim.lsp: Active Clients ~
- angularls (id=1, root_dir=/home/me/repos/devgame-neu)
```

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

angularls.log:

```
Info 0    [13:40:46.72] Format host information updated
Info 1    [13:40:46.73] reload projects.
Info 2    [13:40:46.73] Before ensureProjectForOpenFiles:
Info 3    [13:40:46.73] After ensureProjectForOpenFiles:
Info 4    [13:40:46.73] Host file extension mappings updated
Info 5    [13:40:46.73] Host watch options changed to {"watchFile":4,"watchDirectory":0,"fallbackPolling":2}, it will be take effect for next watches.
Info 6    [13:40:46.73] Angular language server process ID: 3760
Info 7    [13:40:46.74] Using typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary v4.9.5 from /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary.js
Info 8    [13:40:46.74] Using @angular/language-service v15.2.7 from /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/node_modules/@angular/language-service/index.js
Info 9    [13:40:46.74] Log file: /home/me/angularls.log
Info 10   [13:40:46.85] Search path: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app
Info 11   [13:40:46.86] For info: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/app.module.ts :: Config file name: /home/sisyph0s/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json
Info 12   [13:40:46.86] Creating configuration project /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json
Info 13   [13:40:46.88] Loading new project: Creating possible configured project for /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/app.module.ts to open
Info 14   [13:40:46.110] Config: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json : {
 "rootNames": [
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/main.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/app-routing.module.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/app.component.spec.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/app.component.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/app.module.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/home.component.spec.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/home.component.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/challenges/challenges.component.spec.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/challenges/challenges.component.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/leaderboards/leaderboards.component.spec.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/leaderboards/leaderboards.component.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/profile/profile.component.spec.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/profile/profile.component.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/projects/projects.component.spec.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/projects/projects.component.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/projects/project/project.component.spec.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/projects/project/project.component.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/handwritten-models/home-project.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/handwritten-models/leaderboards-entry.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/handwritten-models/profile.ts",
  "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/handwritten-models/quest.ts"
 ],
 "options": {
  "baseUrl": "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu",
  "outDir": "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/dist/out-tsc",
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "strict": true,
  "noImplicitOverride": true,
  "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "downlevelIteration": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "moduleResolution": 2,
  "importHelpers": true,
  "target": 9,
  "module": 7,
  "useDefineForClassFields": false,
  "lib": [
   "lib.es2022.d.ts",
   "lib.dom.d.ts"
  ],
  "configFilePath": "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json"
 }
}
Info 15   [13:40:46.365] Loading global plugin @angular/language-service
Info 16   [13:40:46.365] Enabling plugin @angular/language-service from candidate paths: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/node_modules/@angular/language-service/index.js,/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsserverlibrary.js/../../..
Info 17   [13:40:46.365] Loading @angular/language-service from /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/node_modules/@angular/language-service/index.js (resolved to /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/node_modules/@angular/language-service/index.js/node_modules)
Info 18   [13:40:46.520] Angular compiler options for /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json: {
  "baseUrl": "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu",
  "outDir": "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/dist/out-tsc",
  "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
  "strict": true,
  "noImplicitOverride": true,
  "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
  "noImplicitReturns": true,
  "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "downlevelIteration": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "moduleResolution": 2,
  "importHelpers": true,
  "target": 9,
  "module": 7,
  "useDefineForClassFields": false,
  "lib": [
    "lib.es2022.d.ts",
    "lib.dom.d.ts"
  ],
  "configFilePath": "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json",
  "genDir": "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu",
  "basePath": "/home/me/repos/devgame-neu",
  "enableI18nLegacyMessageIdFormat": false,
  "strictInjectionParameters": true,
  "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
  "strictTemplates": true,
  "compileNonExportedClasses": false
}
Info 19   [13:40:46.521] Plugin validation succeeded
Info 20   [13:40:46.540] Starting updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json
Info 21   [13:40:47.836] Finishing updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json Version: 1 structureChanged: true structureIsReused:: Not Elapsed: 1295.9969760002568ms
Info 22   [13:40:47.836] Project '/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json' (Configured)
Info 23   [13:40:47.836]    Files (371)

Info 24   [13:40:47.836] -----------------------------------------------
Info 25   [13:40:49.52] Enabling Ivy language service for /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json.
Info 26   [13:40:49.53] Starting updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json
Info 27   [13:40:49.104] Finishing updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json Version: 2 structureChanged: true structureIsReused:: Not Elapsed: 51.891818000003695ms
Info 28   [13:40:49.105] Different program with same set of files
Info 29   [13:40:49.244] Starting updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json
Info 30   [13:40:49.324] Finishing updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json Version: 3 structureChanged: true structureIsReused:: Not Elapsed: 80.09762700088322ms
Info 31   [13:40:49.324] Project '/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json' (Configured)
Info 32   [13:40:49.324]    Files (385)

Info 33   [13:40:49.324] -----------------------------------------------
Info 34   [13:41:25.690] Search path: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/profile
Info 35   [13:41:25.690] For info: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/src/app/components/home/profile/profile.component.ts :: Config file name: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json
Info 36   [13:41:25.992] Starting updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json
Info 37   [13:41:26.24] Finishing updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json Version: 4 structureChanged: false structureIsReused:: Completely Elapsed: 31.892907000146806ms
Info 38   [13:41:26.24] Different program with same set of files
Info 39   [13:41:26.115] Starting updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json
Info 40   [13:41:26.172] Finishing updateGraphWorker: Project: /home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json Version: 5 structureChanged: true structureIsReused:: Not Elapsed: 56.91861300077289ms
Info 41   [13:41:26.172] Project '/home/me/repos/devgame-neu/tsconfig.json' (Configured)
Info 42   [13:41:26.172]    Files (386)

Info 43   [13:41:26.172] -----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What plugin did you installed for code-completion or for code-formatting? I believe the connection with the LSP server is only the first part of the configuration.

Comment: I'm using cmp for my code completion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found out why the code completion isn't working!!

After tracing the processes spawned by vscode when opening an angular project. I found out that vscode spawned both ngserver (Angular) and tsserver (TypeScript), and I didn't install typescript for my nvim...

After I installed the tsserver and configured it, everything is working properly! I didn't know that many LSP-clients could be attached to 1 buffer..

If something like this happen to your nvim but not to your vscode, you could look for processes that were spawned by vscode by using `ps aux | less` and then you could cross-check it with your nvim :)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to install additional package for:

- Code Completion (e.g. [nvim-cmp](https://github.com/hrsh7th/nvim-cmp))
- Code Formatting (e.g. [null-ls](https://github.com/jose-elias-alvarez/null-ls.nvim))
- ...

Comment: oops i forgot to mention all of my installed plugins.. I installed nvim-cmp already but i don't have null-ls.

Comment: Good :-) Is `nvim-cmp` configured correctly?

Comment: I think it's configured correctly, since i can use it for other languages (Rust, python, lua, etc.). For the capabilities I use `require('cmp_nvim_lsp').default_capabilities()` and my on_attach is just keymap binding.